# Instantiate a Vue3 Component without mounting to DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Say i create a Vue3 component like this

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

var instance = defineComponent({
  computed:{ 
    message() {
       return 'Hello world'
    }
  }
})
```

I can easily instantiate it by adding it to the DOM like this:

```html
<component :is="instance"/>
```

But suppose i don't want to add it to the DOM, i just want to be able to use the reactive properties and VueJS component magic.

Is there a way to create an instance of the component and interact with it in javascript without using the `<component>` tag like so:

```js
console.log(instance.message) //hoping to log 'Hello World'
```

In Vue 2 it was easy, in Vue 3 it's like pulling teeth trying to find an answer out there.

Comment: why would you want to have a component that you are not using in the DOM? Would a plugin or some other means be not better suited for that?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a component not being mounted, maybe you can achieve the same by writting a composable using the vue core api (`ref`, `reactive`, `computed()` methods)

Comment: I have my reasons, Essentially i'm wanting to create a service, and using the Options API and layout makes sense for this particular use case. (it's a unique use case)

Comment: "In Vue 2 it was easy" I could be confusing my goals with yours, but what exactly did you do in Vue 2 to accomplish this?

Comment: One reason why you would want to render a component outside the DOM is if you want to pass the resulting DOM objects to another library which is responsible for inserting it in the DOM.

Comment: @user1447679 in VUE2: const app = new Vue({...});
const vm = app.$mount();
console.log(vm);. It is also working in nodejs! Vue3 is biggest breaking changer all over the world. Many usefull officialy documented Vue2 usages has no alternatives in Vue3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reactive object anywhere with the composition API.

Here is an example:

https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/home-rolled-store-with-the-vue-js-composition-api/

Comment: Thanks, This link is very helpful, i was really hoping to lay it out using the Options API. But i think i can shim together something similar using some of the helpful information on this page.

Comment: You can easily keep your component defined with the Option API and add some reactive object defined with the Composition API. One of the progressive aspect of Vue power ! Features on demand...